# woocommerce list product by id

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

i have product cat with id=5 and have 10 product

i show list 5 product by id as

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'product_cat' => 5 );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product;

**** loop code *****

endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
```

but is error code(don't show any product). if i change `'product_cat' => 5` by slug as `'product_cat' => 'slug_name'` is true.

How to show product by `id = 5`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use "tax query" like this:

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'product', 
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'terms'    => 5,
        ),
    ),
);
```

Using taxonomy name (`product_cat`) as WP_Query parameter is deprecated.